# ¿Como clonar un solo elemento de una clase en jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

¡Hola!
Lo que ocurre es que tengo siguiente código html que es para crear objetos dinámicos:

```html
<!doctype html>
    <html lang="es-mx">
    <head>
        <style>
        .opcion{
            width: 100%;
            margin: 0px auto 10px auto;
            border-radius: 5px;
            padding: 10px;
            background: rgb(200, 200, 230);
            font-size: 1.2em;
            font-weight: bold;
        }

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>Clonando elementos</h2><br>
        <button type="button" onclick="crearItems()">Presioname</button>
        <div id="elementos">
            <div class="row opcion">
                <div class="opc-contenido" class="media-body">
                    <a class="mt-0">Item 1</a>
                    <p class="mb-0">Elemento</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js" integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60="crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script>
        function crearItems()
        {
           $('.opcion').clone().appendTo('#elementos');
        }
</script>
    </body>
</html>
```

El problema radica en que como es una clase, pues cuando hay un elemento, lo copia y lo inserta, pero al ser ya dos elementos con la misma clase, al volver cliquear copia los dos y los inserta, al hacerlo otra vez copia los 4, y así sucesivamente hasta que se cuelgue tu computadora...
Pero lo que quiero es que solo se clone un elemento cada que hago clic, NO TODOS. ¿Cómo se podría solucionar eso?
Gracias

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes utilizar `:first` de jQuery asi:

```html
<!doctype html>
    <html lang="es-mx">
    <head>
        <style>
        .opcion{
            width: 100%;
            margin: 0px auto 10px auto;
            border-radius: 5px;
            padding: 10px;
            background: rgb(200, 200, 230);
            font-size: 1.2em;
            font-weight: bold;
        }

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>Clonando elementos</h2><br>
        <button type="button" onclick="crearItems()">Presioname</button>
        <div id="elementos">
            <div class="row opcion">
                <div class="opc-contenido" class="media-body">
                    <a class="mt-0">Item 1</a>
                    <p class="mb-0">Elemento</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js" integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60="crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script>
        function crearItems()
        {
           $('.opcion:first').clone().appendTo('#elementos');
        }
</script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: :') llevo como 5 días buscando por qué no me servía a mi algo parecido y ya me funcionó con lo que dice en su respuesta, yo estaba usando :first-child y no ....